# h5ai: subfolders are empty

Tags: apache, debian

I manage to install h5ai on debian with Apache but I have an issue.

I have unzipped h5ai in my /var/www/files folder and when I go on "http://tmp.domain.com", I can see all the content of my "files" folder. But when I click on one of the sub-folders, h5ai says this folders is empty. Same for every sub-folders of /files...
And when I refresh the page of one of these empty folders (http://tmp.domain.com/nameoffolder), Apache index is shown again but this time with the content of the folder.

I have installed it with Apache and added the next lines at the end of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/files
        ServerName  tmp.domain.com

        <Directory /var/www/torrent>
                Options Indexes

                AuthType Digest
                AuthName "Access restricted"
                AuthDigestDomain "http://tmp.domain.com"
                AuthDigestProvider file
                AuthUserFile /home/tulleb/.htdigest
                Require valid-user

                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php _h5ai/server/php/index.php
        </Directory>

        CustomLog /dev/null "combined"
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dl-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried a chmod -R 777 on the /files folder but it doesn't make any difference.

Do you have any ideas..? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the leading slash:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /_h5ai/server/php/index.php
                                    ↑
```

Answer (score 0):

The torrent folder is (as I see it) password protected. Disable it to test h5ai. And check your apache logs `dl-error.log`, you might have the error there.

Comment: I already tried to comment the lines `AuthType Digest
                AuthName "Access restricted"
                AuthDigestDomain "http://tmp.domain.com"
                AuthDigestProvider file
                AuthUserFile /home/tulleb/.htdigest
                Require valid-user` but it didn't make a change.